# Why can we customize ctors & dtors but not accessors?

Tags: c++, oop, getter-setter, accessor, customization-point

<sub>(This is *not* a question about overloading operator. in general.)</sub>

We know that [there are many good reasons to use setter and getter methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/1593077)

Well, then, it seems strange to me these are not customization points of member access i.e. if class A has a data member x, then the use of x in an lvalue context will not really just use x, but rather call some method (say `A::get_x_lvalue()`, never mind the syntax) which defaults to

```
typename std::add_reference<decltype(x)>::type A::get_x_lvalue() {  return x; }
```

and can be implemented as an override, and similarly when x is used in a prvalue constant will call an overridable

```
decltype(x) A::get_x_prvalue() const { return x; }
```

... analogously to, say, [how you do this in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26296497/1593077).

My question are:

- Historically, why was this not added to the language along with customizable copy constructors, assignment operators and destructors?
- Has something like this been officially proposed? If so, what's its status or why was it rejected?
- Are there significant detriments to such a scheme, other than: 1. Slower compilation and 2. Not being able to "trust" the period in my_a.x to be just a plain access?

Comment: " there are many good reasons to use setter and getter methods" - even more not to.

Comment: Are you asking why there aren't properties in C++?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: There are also many good reasons not to implement a copy constructor, assignment operator, move ctor, move assignment and dtor...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I guess you could phrase the question that way; but I'm being specific, i.e. I'm asking why _historically_, and also what are the detriments of this being allowed.

Comment: You _never_ absolutely need getters and setters (they are a design feature), but C++'s value-based types will _often_ need the functions you mention.

Comment: Most types need to be instantiated and destructed. Most types do not need direct access to their data members via member functions.

Comment: Setters and getters, if they give access to a data member, are a failure of encapsulation. So making that easy would not be a good move. Setting and getting a *property* of a type, without the requirement of a matching data member, is a different matter. Your question seems to be focused on the anti-pattern version.